# How to normalize matplotlib colormap on Natural Logarithm scale

Tags: matplotlib, color-mapping, norm

I would like to use imshow for plotting a matrix whose elements are in [1, 64]. To normalise the colormap, I could only find "LogNorm", however, I need something like "LnNorm", normalising the matrix elements on natural logarithm scale. Is there a way that I could do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Super hacky, but you could take the `np.log` of your data and show those values on an arithmetically normalized color scale. You could even reassign tick labels to show the correct values.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. You are right. It seems I cannot do it directly using "norm".

Comment: Actually, for the colormap itself, the base of the logarithm does not matter (to me `log` mean natural logarithm anyway, as it does to numpy). A change in base only corresponds to a rescaling of the log values, but since they get normalised to the full range of the colormap afterwards anyways, that rescaling does not matter. What you are really looking for, is a different formatter for the colorbar!